# Why using a synchronized keyword when we have a simpler way

Tags: java

Using a variable we can ensure that only one method execution is in progress at any time, please see below the proposed code. I am wondering why do we use synchronized then?

```
public class Test {
private static boolean lock = false;

public void testMethod() {
    if(lock){
        System.out.println("Method run is in progress");
        return;
    }
    lock=true;
    try{
        System.out.println("Doing some stuffs here");
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
    finally{
       lock=false;
    }
    return;
}
}
```

Comment: No you can't... Two threads going in will both encounter `lock==false` and continue their way.

Comment: in your example if the method is locked its main body will not be executed. Whereas synchronization makes a thread wait and then continue execution.

Comment: Thanks   @wero  this seems to be one of the good reason

Comment: Please don't use a downvote to reflect your dismay at the apparent obvious nature of a question. IMHO this question is well-posed.

Comment: Guys, please remember that basic questions are not necessary bad question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that simple.

A simple counter-example to your scheme: if two threads encounter your function `testMethod` at the same time, then both could see `lock` as being `false`.

The same applies to the code in your `finally` block.

Answer (score 1):

Things that `synchronized` offers that your "lock" doesn't

1. Synchronized is `reentrant`, threads holding the lock can re-enter the critical section.
2. Synchronized provides fresh visibility for the mutex and the data in the section, yours will fail to get the actual value of `lock` in a multi-threaded env.

Do some research on `race-conditions` and `memory-barriers`